Tigervnc server: do I have to start a specific 'instance'?
I am trying to set up a tigervnc server on Pop! OS. When I try to start the server in systemd using sudo systemctl start tigervncserver@ , I get the following error:

Failed to start tigervncserver@.service: Unit name
tigervncserver@.service is missing the instance name. See system logs
and 'systemctl status tigervncserver@.service' for details.

This seems to imply that I have to start an instance of the server that is linked to a specific display (i.e. with sudo systemctl start tigervncserver@:1). However, aren't the display numbers linked to individual users? So, isn't that command starting the VNC server for just one specific user? Is there some way to start a 'general' VNC server daemon, that will start VNC sessions for whichever users log in?
Sorry, perhaps I'm just confused about how this is supposed to work.


However, aren't the display numbers linked to individual users? So, isn't that command starting the VNC server for just one specific user?

Yes, that's exactly how it works most of the time.

Is there some way to start a 'general' VNC server daemon, that will start VNC sessions for whichever users log in?

While possible in theory, I haven't seen any actual VNC server that would support that kind of usage (and in particular, not in a way that would allow the same port to be reused for different sessions concurrently). It has traditionally been a 1:1 thing and seems to have mostly remained so.
RDP, on the other hand, typically does work exactly the way you want – though it can also be used "straight to session", but with Xrdp you can get a login screen and route users to their own sessions all on the same service.

Thanks for your answer. Yes, it seems like RDP might be closer to what I'm looking for and I will give Xrdp a try. It seems like VNC is not really suitable for a multi-user environment, if servers have to be started that are linked to individual users.
